# Как соединить Entry и Button в Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, entry

Как сделать так, чтобы когда ты печатаешь в поисковой строке слово "черепаха" и запускаешь кнопку, перо превращается в черепаху ?

Вот код :

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import *

pensize(4)
left(90)
shape("square")
color('#717171')
setup(550, 550)

def p():
    if entry_1 == 'Черепаха':
        shape('turtle')

btn_ton = Button(height=2, width=4, bg='#717171', command=p, text='↑', fg='white')
btn_ton.place(x=505, y=507)

entry_1 = Entry(width=50, font=('Gabriola 17'))
entry_1.pack(side=TOP)

done()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно обращаться к тексту в `entry_1`:

```
def p():
    if entry_1.get().lower() == 'черепаха':
        shape('turtle')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить значение `Entry` через метод `get`:

```py
# импорт
from tkinter import *
from turtle import *


# параметры
pensize(4)
left(90)
shape('square')
color('#717171')
setup(550, 550)


# функция для смены формы черепахи (переименована)
def change_shape():
    if entry.get() == 'Черепаха': # получаем значение Entry через метод get()
        shape('turtle')


# кнопка (переименована)
button = Button(height=2, width=4, bg='#717171', command=change_shape, text='↑', fg='white')
button.place(x=505, y=507)

# поле ввода (переименовано)
entry = Entry(width=50, font=('Gabriola', 17)) # шрифт лучше указывать так
entry.pack(side=TOP)

# готово
done()
```

> **Совет**: почитайте PEP-8, как правильно оформлять код.

Answer (score -1):

Есть два способа установить или изменить текст Entry виджета Tkinter, нажав кнопку Tkinter,
Tkinter delete и insert метод
StringVar Метод Tkinter
Tkinter delete и insert способ установки содержимого Entry
Entry У виджета Tkinter нет специального set метода для настройки содержимого Entry. Сначала необходимо удалить существующее содержимое, а затем вставить новое содержимое, если нужно полностью изменить содержимое.
Завершите рабочие коды для ввода текста Entrydelete и insert методы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если textEntry значение обновлено, чтобы иметь новое значение text, то виджеты, textvariable связанные с ним, будут автоматически обновлены.

Comment: а почему все в виде скриншотов???

Comment: Текстовую информацию (код в данном случае) нужно добавлять текстом, а не скриншотами.

Comment: Исправлю чуть погодя, сделаю текстом. Просто писать с телефона за рулем очень неудобно, а информация есть. Вечером сяду за комп, исправлю.